# how to get this kind of date time format in moment js along with the name of TZ?

Tags: datetime, timezone, momentjs

```
endDate = moment(endDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z")
```

It is giving me output like this "2016-11-30 00:00 +05:30"

but i want to know how to get datetime with below format, Includes name of time zone.

```
Sat Feb 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
moment.tz(endDate, 'Asia/Kolkata').format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z zz')
"Wed May 11 2016 18:15:24 GMT+05:30 IST"
```

You can do in this way.